# mySql - updating by comparing rows in same table

Tags: mysql, compare

I want to update a column by comparing each row to all other rows in the table but I cant figure out how to distinguish the column names in the row being updated with the rows being searched through.

Here's a simplified example...

people:
    `+--------+-----+----------------+`
    `| name   | age | nameClosestAge |`
    `+--------+-----+----------------+`
    `| alice  |  20 |                |`
    `| bob    |  30 |                |`
    `| clive  |  22 |                |`
    `| duncan |  24 |                |`
    `+--------+-----+----------------+`

To fill in the 'nameClosestAge' column with the name of the person that is closest in age to each person, you could do this...

```
create temporary table peopleTemp like people;
insert into peopleTemp select * from people;
update people set nameClosestAge = 
(select name from peopleTemp where people.name != peopleTemp.name 
order by abs(people.age - peopleTemp.age) asc limit 1);
```

Which produces this....
`+--------+-----+----------------+`
`| name   | age | nameClosestAge |`
`+--------+-----+----------------+`
`| alice  |  20 | clive          |`
`| bob    |  30 | duncan         |`
`| clive  |  22 | alice          |`
`| duncan |  25 | clive          |`
`+--------+-----+----------------+`

Surely there is a way to do this without creating a duplicate table.
I'm looking for the most efficient method here as I have a very large table and its taking too long to update.
I'm using mySql with PHP.

Comment: It really makes little sense to _store_ the nameClosestAge (unless that's for caching purposes) as it creates redundancy...

Comment: Jasper. This is a simplified example. The calculation for the updated field is more complex for the real problem.

Comment: ...and later queries require me to search through the updated field.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform this with just one sub-query and no temp table.

```
SELECT name, age, (
  SELECT name
  FROM people
  WHERE name != ppl.name
  ORDER BY ABS( people.age - ppl.age ) 
  LIMIT 1
  ) AS nameClosestAge
FROM people AS ppl;
```

Checked and works :)

EDIT: If you want to be able to work with the calc'ed row, you can use a view;

```
CREATE VIEW people_close AS 
  SELECT name, age, (
    SELECT name
    FROM people
    WHERE name != ppl.name
    ORDER BY ABS( people.age - ppl.age ) 
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS nameClosestAge
  FROM people AS ppl;
```

You can't update the calculated field but can query against it easily.

Comment: Thanks pharalia. However I cant figure out from your solution how to do the update. I.e. this doesnt work...
update people AS ppl set nameClosestAge =
(SELECT name
FROM people
WHERE name != ppl.name
ORDER BY ABS( people.age - ppl.age ) 
LIMIT 1
)

Comment: OK.. that's a shame. You can't use the table you are updating in a sub-query. Works with the original temp table though using this, but that defeats the object of the question... 

`create temporary table peopleTemp like people;
insert into peopleTemp select * from people;

UPDATE people SET closest = (SELECT name FROM peopleTemp WHERE people.name != peopleTemp.name ORDER BY ABS( people.age - peopleTemp.age ) LIMIT 1);`

Another way you could do it it to create a view with the nameClosestAge column included.